# Mojolicious, redirects, session and trying to create an authentication system

Tags: perl, session, authentication, mojolicious

I'm trying to get away from Basic Auth in my Mojolicious application.  I am able to detect the absence of a session key and redirect to a login page.  The login page then posts to my application and I authenticate to a back end process.  That back end process is returning success and then my mojo app sets the session like thus:

```
$self->session( user => $name, groups => $groups );
```

in debugging this, $name and $group are both defined and valid.  I then wish to redirect into the "protected" space of my app.  The redirect lands in the right place but then fails to detect the $self->session('user') (is undef when debugging)  I end up redirecting back to login repeatedly.

I'll include snippets of the setup below.  What am I missing?

MyApp.pm

```
my $r = $self->routes;
$r->route('/verify')->via('post')->to('util-auth#verify')->name('verify');
$r->route('/login')->via('get')->to('util-auth#login')->name('login');
my $app = $r->under('/myapp')->to('util-auth#check');

$app->route('/foo')->via('get')->to('controller-api#foo')->name('foo');
```

MyApp::Util::Auth

```
sub verify {
    my $self = shift;
    my $name = $self->param('username');
    my $pass = $self->param('password');
    my $dest = "/myapp/foo"; # in the protected area

    if ( $self->authenticate($name, $pass) ) {
        my $groups = $self->get_groups($name);
        $self->session(
            user => $name,
            groups => $groups,
        );
    }
    else {
        $self->flash( message => "invalid login..." );
    }
    $self->redirect_to($dest);
}

sub login {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render();    # renders the login form
}

sub check {
    my $self = shift;
    my $user = $self->session('user');
    return 1 if defined $user;
    $self->redirect_to('/login');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't be easier to use for example: https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::Authentication ?

Comment: Not necessarily, plus I want to understand why this doesn't work.  The big mystery to me is why is the the session cookie not available after a redirect.

Comment: Did you found an answer? I am now in the very same situation. Just after a correct "$self->authenticate" the session has the right value for "auth_data", but after redirecting or loading another page, that value is gone from the session.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and I ended up putting these in stash. I think session is string based, mainly because a cookie is set with session info.

Answer (score 1):

Why your `verify` function accept name, pass via @_ variable?

May be need to use `$self->param('name')` and `$self->param('pass')`?

See working example here:
https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/bdf6f22c00fc51798c43

Comment: You are correct, and I that is what I have in my code... I just typed it in wrong for this example.  I will look at your gist and see if I can see any differences.  I'll edit my post as well.  Thanks